# R Durbin Watson Test for a list of lm objects

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a list with two (or more) `lm` objects. Now I want to execute a Durbin-Watson test either with `dwtest` or `durbinWatsonTest` from `lmtest` or `car` respectively on both `lm` objects at once, ie. I would like to do

```
dwtest(reg_objects)
durbinWatsonTest(reg_objects)
```

When I do this, I get the following: using `dwtest`: values are `NA`. Using `durbinWatsonTest`:

```
Error in durbinWatsonTest.default(reg_1y$call) : 
requires vector of residuals
```

To facilitate the idea, I have generated a list object of 5 lm objects:

```
#  non-sensical lm!
set.seed(123)
y <- 1 + rnorm(10)

#  this makes a list of 5 lm's using the response data 'y'
data <- replicate( 5 , lm(  y ~ 1 + rnorm(10) ) , simpl = FALSE )
```

Can you help me with this issue?
Andreas

Edit: same question for `bgtest`, `bptest` and `sctest`. Note: `sctest` is from `strucchange`.

Comment: so `reg_objects` is a list of models? did you read the help pages to those functions or at least look at the examples?

Comment: Sure I did and I also tried, see above error messages. Interestingly, I could not find any example in any of the cases for more than one regression object in one go. So I believe this is a fairly interesting general question.

Comment: well both take one model at a time, so you'd have to write some kind of loop: `lapply(1:5, function(x) car::dwt(eval(data[[x]]$call)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_dw_stat <- list()

for(dw in seq(data)) {

  my_dw_stat[[dw]] <- dwtest(data[[dw]]$model[, 1] ~ data[[dw]]$model[, 2])

}
```